# How to use component on Email Template to calculate Table SUM

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, email-template, controller-extension

I have an Email template with a table, that I want to have a sum of a column. I tried to use a component with a custom controller, but after a couple of hours i didn't achieve any result.

In my Email Template, I have this:

```
<c:TableSummary ad="{!relatedTo.Cliente__c}"></c:TableSummary>
```

This is my component:

```
<apex:component controller="TableSummaryExtension" access="Global">
<apex:attribute name="ad" type="Id" description="Current Id" assignTo="{!CurrentId}"  />
    <div style="float: right;margin-top:5px;padding-right:1px" align="right">
    <table class="gridtable" style="width:200px">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <apex:outputText value="Total"/>
            </th>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!SumSaldo}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <apex:outputText value="Juros"/>
            </th>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!SumJuros}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <apex:outputText value="Total Geral"/>
            </th>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!GrandTotal}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

And this is my Controller:

```
public with sharing class TableSummaryExtension {

    public List<Cobranca__c> cobrancas {get; set;}
    public Id CurrentId {get; set;}
    public Account conta {get; set;}
    public Decimal SumSaldo {get;set;}
    public Decimal SumJuros {get;set;}
    public Decimal GrandTotal {get;set;}
    public String Filial {get;set;}

    public TableSummaryExtension() {

    }

    public TableSummaryExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    }

    public Decimal getSaldo()
    {
        cobrancas = [select id, name, Vencimento__c, Valor__c, Numero_Lancamento__c,Numero_Fatura__c,
        Estado__c,Data_Emissao__c,Data_Pagamento__c,Numero_Fiscal__c,Cliente__r.Name, Cliente__r.Id ,Dias_em_Atraso__c, Complemento__c,
                     Unidade_de_Neg_cio__c, Juros__c, Cliente__r.Filial__c, Saldo__c, Cliente__r.Owner.Name  from cobranca__c where id in: cobrancas AND cliente__c =: currentId and  Estado__c != 'Fechado'];
        conta = [select id, name, billingstreet, billingcity, billingpostalcode, billingState, ParentId, Filial__c, Owner.Name from Account where id =: currentid];
        SumSaldo=0;
        SumJuros=0;
        GrandTotal=0;
        Filial = cobrancas[0].Cliente__r.Filial__c;
        system.debug(Filial);
        for(Cobranca__c cob : cobrancas)
        {
            if (cob.Saldo__c!=null)
            {
                SumSaldo += cob.Saldo__c;
            }
        }
        return SumSaldo;
    }

    public Decimal getJuros()
    {
        cobrancas = [select id, name, Vencimento__c, Valor__c, Numero_Lancamento__c,Numero_Fatura__c,
        Estado__c,Data_Emissao__c,Data_Pagamento__c,Numero_Fiscal__c,Cliente__r.Name, Cliente__r.Id ,Dias_em_Atraso__c, Complemento__c,
                     Unidade_de_Neg_cio__c, Juros__c, Cliente__r.Filial__c, Saldo__c, Cliente__r.Owner.Name  from cobranca__c where id in: cobrancas AND cliente__c =: currentId and  Estado__c != 'Fechado'];
        conta = [select id, name, billingstreet, billingcity, billingpostalcode, billingState, ParentId, Filial__c, Owner.Name from Account where id =: currentid];
        SumSaldo=0;
        SumJuros=0;
        GrandTotal=0;
        Filial = cobrancas[0].Cliente__r.Filial__c;
        for(Cobranca__c cob : cobrancas)
        {
            if (cob.Juros__c!=null)
            {
                SumJuros += cob.Juros__c;
            }
        }
        return SumJuros;
    }

    public Decimal getGrandTotal()
    {
        GrandTotal = getJuros()+getSaldo();
        return GrandTotal;
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideia why this dont work? I also tried put the query and the calculation inside the standardsetcontroller I didn't achieve any result either.

**update with resolution:**

In the end, it was not necessary to use a component and a controller. I used the component calculations given in the answer below directly in my email template!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be many issues in this code from best practice point of view first of all

1. You are querying the same Object multiple times in different methods
2. There is no limit in your query
3. You are iterating the same query multiple times
4. You are initializing all the variables again in different method. so, in `grandTotal` method, when you call both the methods, **initialization happens multiple times**
   Hence, in method `getJuros` the `sumSaldo` becomes 0 again and vice-versa.

Now, the simplest of fix to your problem is:

- Call the `getGrandTotal` method in the constructor itself, which fixes the issue. Since the initialization did not happen on the page load, the calculation would not happen on page level binding/call

  ```
  public TableSummaryExtension() {
      getGrandTotal();
  }

  public TableSummaryExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
      getGrandTotal();
  }
  ```
- Also remove initialization of `sumSaldo` in `getJuros` method and vice versa. So that both does not become `0` in each method call
- `sumSaldo` become `0` in `getJuros`...and `sumJuros` become `0` in `getSaldo`. So the total become `0`

Now the optimized code:

**Component**

```
<apex:component controller="TableSummaryExtension" access="Global">
<apex:attribute name="ad" type="Id" description="Current Id" assignTo="{!CurrentId}"  />
    <div style="float: right;margin-top:5px;padding-right:1px" align="right">
    <apex:variable var="saldoSum" value="0">
    <apex:variable var="jurosSum" value="0">

    <apex:repeat value="cobrancas" var="cobranaca">
        <apex:variable var="saldoSum" value="{!VALUE(saldoSum)+cobranaca.Saldo__c}" rendered="{!cobranaca.Saldo__c!=null}">
        <apex:variable var="jurosSum" value="{!VALUE(jurosSum)+cobranaca.Juros__c}" rendered="{!cobranaca.Juros__c!=null}">
    </apex:repeat>
    <table class="gridtable" style="width:200px">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <apex:outputText value="Total"/>
            </th>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!saldoSum}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <apex:outputText value="Juros"/>
            </th>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!jurosSum}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <apex:outputText value="Total Geral"/>
            </th>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!VALUE(saldoSum)+VALUE(jurosSum)}"></apex:outputText>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</apex:component>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class TableSummaryExtension {

    public List<Cobranca__c> cobrancas {get; set;}
    public Id CurrentId {get; set;}
    public Account conta {get; set;}
    public String Filial {get;set;}

    public TableSummaryExtension() {
        queryOnLoad();
    }

    public TableSummaryExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        queryOnLoad();
    }

    private void queryOnLoad(){
        List<Cobranca__c> cobrancas = new List<Cobranca__c>();
        cobrancas = [select id, name, Vencimento__c, Valor__c, Numero_Lancamento__c,Numero_Fatura__c,
        Estado__c,Data_Emissao__c,Data_Pagamento__c,Numero_Fiscal__c,Cliente__r.Name, Cliente__r.Id ,Dias_em_Atraso__c, Complemento__c, Unidade_de_Neg_cio__c, Juros__c, Cliente__r.Filial__c, Saldo__c, Cliente__r.Owner.Name  
        from cobranca__c 
        where id in: cobrancas AND cliente__c =: currentId and  Estado__c != 'Fechado' LIMIT 10000];

        conta = [select id, name, billingstreet, billingcity, billingpostalcode, billingState, ParentId, Filial__c, Owner.Name from Account where id =: currentid LIMIT 1];

        Filial = cobrancas[0].Cliente__r.Filial__c;
    }
}
```

It reduces server load-time, and improves performance.

Comment: Hello San! Thanks for your help. Your code makes perfect sense to me, but it wont works. After I change the component, the controller and add the component to the email template, when I try to save the email template appear an error that says: "Attempt to de-reference a null object", and dont show the preview of the template. Any thought from whats happening? Thanks!

Comment: see the updated method `queryOnLoad`. I added initialization for `cobrancas`. I was wondering why have you used `cobrancas` in the `WHERE` condition in your query. It would not make any difference.

Comment: My bad, didn't saw that the list was not being inicialized. Ok, I get no error, and I can see the template. The component is showed, but the fields always remain 0. I cant debug this, its strange, but even that I put a system.debug in my controller and send a email to test, it dont add any log to the registry. Resuming, the component is appearing but the all values are 0!

Comment: remove `id in: cobrancas` from the `WHERE` condition in the page

Comment: San, i found the solution by using your component calculations directly on the email template. Thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, it looks like you have created a property, but values are not being set in those properties. There are multiple ways in which you can fix and optimize it.

You should rather modify your code to mark the properties as just class level variables, so that page gets values from getter methods:-

```
public Decimal SumSaldo;
public Decimal SumJuros;
```

Within your VF page bind your getting methods like:-

Also, you can modify your method "getGrandTotal" to calculate it from variables, instead of calling methods again (to optimize it further).

```
public Decimal getGrandTotal()
{
    return SumSaldo + SumJuros;
}
```

There are other alternatives to optimize it further. Like,

1. you can create a third function, which does all the work of current two methods "getSaldo" and "getJuros", so you fire SOQL query only once and get the calculated values
2. As per the code provided, second SOQL query in both the methods doesn't seem to be solving any purpose:-

   conta = [select id, name, billingstreet, billingcity, billingpostalcode, billingState, ParentId, Filial__c, Owner.Name from Account where id =: currentid];